# Flutter: Run function after GPS is enabled

Tags: flutter

I wanted to run deviceInfo function which is written below once user enabled the GPS/Location Services. Currently it is running only to check  Location Services is enabled or not. If its disabled then it shows alert dialog.

As you can see i am using If condition. If location is disabled then show the alert dialog else proceed to the next step.

Problem is if user enable the locations services then how can i execute code those are written under else condition.

Here is the code.

```
  Future<void> deviceInfo() async {
      DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      print(androidInfo.androidId);
      print('Is Physical Device: ${androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice}');
      physicaldevice = androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice;
      if(physicaldevice == true){
       
        var isGpsEnabled = await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();

         if(isGpsEnabled == false){
          setState(() {
              visible = false;
          });
          _showAlert(context);
          print(isGpsEnabled);
         

        }else{
         ------ Some Codes if GPS is enabled ------
    }
```

Here is the AlertBox for GPS enable message

```
   void _showAlert(BuildContext context) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Error"),
            content: Text("Location Service is disabled. Please enable it."),
             actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(child: Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () {
                final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
                  action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS');
              intent.launch();
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
              })],
          )
      );
    }
```

In Simple words i want to re-run DeviceInfo function once GPS is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Timer.periodic if isGpsEnabled is false

```
    Future<void> deviceInfo() async {
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
  print(androidInfo.androidId);
  print('Is Physical Device: ${androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice}');
  physicaldevice = androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice;
  if(physicaldevice == true){
   
    var isGpsEnabled = await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();

     if(isGpsEnabled == false){
      setState(() {
          visible = false;
      });
      _showAlert(context);
      print(isGpsEnabled);
       // new code //
       Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
       var isGpsEnabled = await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();
       if (isGpsEnabled) {
       timer.cancel();
        ------ Some Codes if GPS is enabled ------
       }
});
  
     

    }else{
     ------ Some Codes if GPS is enabled ------
}
```

Comment: You solution worked man. Only one issue i am facing. If user didn't enabled the location and go back then alert box is no more visible as user already clicked on Ok.

Comment: I managed it to work .   Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(_showAlert); added this code inside the Time.Periodic. Thanks a ton for your help.